# Measure $m=\mu$ if $\int fdm=\int fd\mu$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $X$ is a locally compact Hausdorff space, $m,\mu$ are two Borel measures, if for any $f\in C_c(X)$, $\int fdm=\int fd\mu$, is it true that $m=\mu$?

Comment: Can you assume the measures are regular?

Comment: If you assume that the two measures are regular, then everything is trivial, since every Borel can be approximated by compact sets.